# Javascript code is not working after updating a link via Ajax Call in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress website that contains a file storage.
The layout is as follows:
On the left side there is a sidebar which shows the complete directory structure.
On the rightside next to the sidebar there is a file list which contains the file names as links.
If you click on the file name, the file gets downloaded via an AJAX call.
Everything works fine until I navigate through the directories.
If I navigate to another directory or click at the sidebar on the same folder the file list gets updated but the download does not work anymore.
How do I update the file list?
I do an ajax call and refresh the directory structure.
I read out the file names from the new directory and run this Javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
   jQuery(".change_dir").click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      file_path = jQuery(this).attr("data-file_path");
      nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce");
      sid = jQuery(this).attr("data-sid");

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "get",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "change_current_directory", file_path : file_path, nonce: nonce, _sid:sid},
         success: function(response) {
             console.log(response);
            if(response.type == "success") {
                var fileList = document.getElementById("file-list");
                var files = response.file_list;
                var links = response.link_list;
                var innerHTMLText="";
                for (var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
                    var tmp= files[i].split("/");
                    var filename = tmp[tmp.length-1];
                    innerHTMLText+= '<a class="download_file" data-nonce="' + response.nonce + '" data-file_path="' + files[i] + '" data-sid="' + response.sid + '" href="' + links[i] + '">'+filename+'</a><br>';
                }
                console.log(innerHTMLText);
                fileList.innerHTML=innerHTMLText;
            }
            else {
               alert("Change failed.");
            }
         },
         error: function(error) {
            alert("Error occured: " + error.status + " " + error.statusText);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

It updates the file list and the link is the same as at the beginning (when the site loads the first time)
but the download action does not take place.
The download and the file-list update is implemented as a wordpress plugin.
When I now click on the file to download it, the plugins .php file is triggered but it does not trigger the .js file to execute the download on the user side.
Here is the code that will be executed:
1st part is the template code (generates the link for the download)

```
function loadDirectory($url,$data_field,$session_id,$path){
    $phpCode="";
    
    $data_field['_sid']=$session_id;
    $data_field['folder_path']=$path;
    //result contains directory structure
    $result = json_decode(get_raw_curl_data ($url,$data_field),true);
    //echo var_dump($result);
    $check_success = $result["success"];
    if (!$check_success){
        return "Some Error";
    }
    
    $allFiles = $result["data"]["files"];
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce("some_secret_nonce");

    foreach ($allFiles as $filemeta){
        if (!$filemeta["isdir"]){
            //filter for files, display the filename
            //and link it to the code that shall be executed
            $tmpName = $filemeta["path"];
            $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=download&_sid='.$session_id.'&file_path='.$tmpName.'&nonce='.$nonce);
            $phpCode = $phpCode.'<a class="download_file" data-nonce="' . $nonce . '" data-file_path="' . $tmpName . '" data-sid="' . $session_id . '" href="' . $link . '">'.$filemeta["name"].'</a><br>';
        }
    }
    //echo var_dump($phpCode);
    unset($filemeta);
    return $phpCode;
}
```

This code works fine when the page is loaded for the first time. To refresh the file list when I change the directory, the sidebar is initialized with this code:

```
function loadSidebar($url,$data_field,$session_id,$path){
    $phpCode="";
    
    $data_field['_sid']=$session_id;
    $data_field['folder_path']=$path;
    //result contains directory structure
    $result = json_decode(get_raw_curl_data ($url,$data_field),true);
    //echo var_dump($result);
    $check_success = $result["success"];
    if (!$check_success){
        return "Some Error";
    }
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce("another_secret_nonce");
    $allFiles = $result["data"]["files"];
    foreach ($allFiles as $filemeta){
        //echo var_dump($filemeta);
        //filter for directories, display the dir name
        //and link it to the code that shall be executed
        if ($filemeta["isdir"]){
            $tmpName = $filemeta["path"];
            $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=change_current_directory&_sid='.$session_id.'&file_path='.$tmpName.'&nonce='.$nonce);
            $dirlist = dirListFromCurrentDir($url,$data_field,$session_id,$path."/".$filemeta["name"]);
            if (count($dirlist)>0){
                $phpCode = $phpCode."<button class='dropdown-btn'>".$filemeta["name"]."<i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></button>";
                $phpCode = $phpCode."<div class='dropdown-container'>";
                foreach ($dirlist as $dirname){
                    $phpCode = $phpCode."<a class='change_dir' data-nonce='" . $nonce . "' data-file_path='" . $tmpName . "/" . $dirname . "' data-sid='" . $session_id . "' href='" . $link . "'>".$dirname."</a>";                    
                }
                $phpCode = $phpCode."</div>";
            }else{
                $phpCode = $phpCode."<a class='change_dir' data-nonce='" . $nonce . "' data-file_path='" . $tmpName . "' data-sid='" . $session_id . "' href='" . $link . "'>".$filemeta["name"]."</a>";
            }
        }
    }
    unset($filemeta);
    return $phpCode;
}
```

The following code is executed if I change the directory:

```
function change_current_directory() {
    function get_raw_curl_data($url,$data_field)
    {//code not relevant}
   function loadDirectory($url,$data_field,$session_id,$path)
        {//code not relevant}
   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "another_secret_nonce")) {
      exit("Woof Woof Woof");
   }   
   
   // fetch sid and path
   $sid = $_REQUEST["_sid"];
   $file_path = $_REQUEST["file_path"];
   $file_name = end(explode("/",$file_path));
   //Download File
   $url_files = "https://apiurl";
   $listFiles_field = [//APIData];

   $allFiles = ladeDirectory($url_files,$listFiles_field,$sid,$file_path);

   $download_nonce = wp_create_nonce("some_secret_nonce");
   $result['type'] = "success";
   //list with all file names
   $result['file_list'] = $allFiles[0];
   //list with the generated admin_url() link for each file
   $result['link_list']= $allFiles[1];
   $result['nonce']=$download_nonce;
   $result['sid']=$sid;
   // Check if action was fired via Ajax call. If yes, JS code will be triggered, else the user is redirected to the post page
   //At this point, the page refreshes without an action
   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
      
      $result = json_encode($result);
      echo $result;
   }
   else {
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
   }
   // don't forget to end your scripts with a die() function - very important
   die();
```

The JS code (first code block) should now be executed.
I appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: _“but it does not trigger the .js file to execute the download on the user side”_ - where is that part of the code? It might bind some event handlers to _existing_ elements, but when you replace those elements with new ones after your AJAX call, those event handlers are then probably missing.

Comment: add download attribute to the anchor tag innerHTML string. You don't need js for that.

Comment: In case if there is a separate js file inside a php file that is called via ajax, the js needs to be self executing

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies! 
@AtulKumar I am pretty sure that I need js because the file to be downloaded does not exist in a wordpress directory. If you click the link, the file is downloaded from another server via an API (this has to do with some data protection issues). If you still see a way to do this without using js please let me know, it would simplify the whole process a lot.

Comment: @04FS I think this is the problem, I now have to find a way to add these event handlers...and I already have an idea. I will inform you about success/failure.

Comment: Try wrapping the function in () i,e **(function() { })()**. This will execute the function as soon as it loads

Comment: @04FS I added the missing parts of the code because my idea didn't worked out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use _event delegation_ to add your event listeners. `jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.change_dir', function(e) {…} )` (Instead of `document`, you can also bind this to a common ancestor element of the links that is “closer” in the DOM structure, it just needs to be one that does not get changed by the AJAX request.)

Comment: @04FS thank you for your comment. This looks pretty much like what i was searching for. I changed the code but it does not work. I guess this is due to my missing knowledge with event delegation. Where do I add these event listeners? I guess I have to initialize them in another code block? Let's say these filenames are listed in a <div> box with the id "file-list". Where do I say that this div-box shall listen for click events? And what exactly do I have to write there? Because of the use of "my own" plugin, the JS Code is placed in a separate file. May this cause problems too?
Thanks!

Comment: Same place where you added the click handlers before. `jQuery('#file-list').on( 'click', '.change_dir', …)` The element `#file-list` must exist at this point, and it must not be replaced with a “new version” of itself after your AJAX request, but looking at your code, that appears to be a given.

Comment: @04FS Thank you, it works! I changed the code at the right place before but the '#' was missing. 
Thank you for your help! I am new to stackoverflow...where do i close the topic and mark your comment as the right answer?